# Implementing a Windows explorer "private mode", save&restore recent documents

Tags: batch-file, explorer, privacy

Windows Explorer is a snitch, and with every version of Windows its tracking of the files you use and the folders you access has become more pervasive.
In Windows 10, if you create a hidden folder with a file "hidden.txt" in it, once you have opened this file,

- the file will be listed under "recent documents"
- the file will be listed in the "recent documents" quick access section of Notepad in the task bar (the "jump list")
- the folder will be among the auto suggestions in the address bar of explorer

Now there are many situations where this isn't desired, and usually people clear the recent documents and the address bar history to get rid of such traces. This however undermines the usefulness of the history, which in even more cases is really useful for quick access.

I would LOVE to have a similar thing as browsers' "Private Mode" for Windows explorer.

QUESTIONS:

- does such a private mode exist?
- do you know of any software or other solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't a built-in private mode in Windows, I set out to write a basic tool for it myself.

For simplicity, I've written this as a batch-file for Windows 10, which backups the recent documents and the jump lists (in the %AppData% folder) and the file explorer's address bar history (in the registry) on the first execution and writes this state back on the second execution.

```
IF EXIST .\temphist GOTO tempexists

mkdir .\temphist
robocopy "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent" .\temphist\recent /MIR
reg EXPORT HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TypedPaths .\temphist\TypedPaths.reg
GOTO end

:tempexists
robocopy .\temphist\recent "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent" /MIR
reg DELETE HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TypedPaths /va /f
reg IMPORT .\temphist\TypedPaths.reg
rmdir /S /Q .\temphist

:end
```

QUESTIONS:

- are there any other places where explorer / Windows leaves file-/folder-usage traces?
- particularly, is there a standard location for windows programs to keep their own 'recently opened'-lists, or will it differ for each program?
- can anyone spot any immediate problems with such a solution?
- this works on Windows 10, would it also work for its predecessors?

By the way: obviously this doesn't hold up in a forensic attack. I guess there will be plenty of traces on the file system level, but at least as far as the GUI is concerned, this should cover most cases (not unlike a browser's private mode).